# Continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$ with neither open nor closed image

Tags: real-analysis

It is easy to construct a continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(\Bbb{R})$ is neither open nor closed in $\Bbb{R}$. For instance, 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}. 
$$
Do we have a characterization of subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ which can be the images of such map?

---

I think one can argue that $[a,b)$ or $(a,b]$ would work. But I don't see how others might work.

Comment: Image of an interval ( in this case $\mathbb{R})$ by continuous function is an interval.

Comment: What about $\sin(\Bbb R)$ or $\arctan(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Any continuous image of $\mathbb R$ must be path-connected, and these are the only path-connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are neither open nor closed, so you are correct.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Those are both closed. He is trying to categorize images which are neither closed nor open.

Comment: Basically, the intermediate value theorem states that the only image of the real line can be an interval of some sort.

Comment: Oops. Nevermind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intermediate value theorem says that if $a<b$ are in the image of $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, then any $c$ with $a\leq c\leq b$ is in the image.

Let $a=\inf_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x)$ and $b=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x)$. Possibly, $a=-\infty$ and/or $b=+\infty$.

Now, the intermediate value theorem shows that any $x\in(a,b)$ is in the range of $f$.

The definition of $\sup$ shows that if $x<a$ or $x>b$ then $x$ is not in the range of $f$.

The only questionable elements are $a,b$. They might or might not be in the range of $f$. If $a=-\infty$ then it can't be. If $b=+\infty$ it can't be. But any other possible combination is allowed.

So, this gives the possible images of a continuous function on $\mathbb R$:

$$(-\infty,+\infty),\\
(-\infty,b),(-\infty,b],\\
[a,b),[a,b],(a,b),(a,b],\\
[a,+\infty),(a,+\infty)$$

Of these, the only ones which are not closed and not open are $(a,b]$ and $[a,b)$, with $a,b$ both real.